# CORS Header not present despite clearly adding it to response

Tags: python, django, cors

I have a Django server that I'm trying to implement sessions for. Everything was working fine when suddenly, last week, get requests started being denied due to:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/<URL> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

However, before sending the response I explicitly add the header:

```
response =  JsonResponse({"success": True}, status=200)
response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = True
return response
```

My `settings.py` seems to be configured correctly, with `corsheaders` and `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` as well as  `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` and `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE`:

The request is as follows:

```
...
fetch(query_url, {credentials: 'include'}).then(d => {
  if( d.status === 200 ) {
    <do stuff>
  }
})
```

Am I missing something? I'm using django 2.1, and unfortunately can't upgrade right now.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the documentation for [Django's CORS](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) package, I realized the problem was this missing config on my `settings.py`:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

A very silly mistake. I'll leave this question up in case someone else runs into the same problem.